# Issue with binding a list in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

i am using visual studio 2017, and xamarin forms pcl project.

I would like to bind an observable collection to a list in my project. My project contains a view and a viewModel.

my ViewModel has a property

```
    public Observable Collection ListOfInformation
{ 
    get { return _listOfInformation;} 
    set{
        if(value!=null) _listOfInformation = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(" ListOfInformation");}
}
```

my View .xaml has

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"  HeightRequest="250" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  TextColor="White" Text="{Binding  DateTime}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

                                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding BookCount}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

And in my view.cs file

```
ViewModel view = new ViewModel;
BindingContext = view;
InitializeComponent();
listView.BindingContext = view;
listView.itemsource = view.ListOfInformation;
```

However, when my list is being updated during runtime when information is loaded, the list is not being updated on the UI. Why?

Comment: Please post the real code for your `ListOfInformation`, as well as the class it's a list of. As it is, this won't even compile.

Comment: How are you updating the list at runtime?  Are you just adding and removing items, are you making changes to individual items, or are you generating an entirely new list?

Comment: In case your source code has it, please remove the space in this statement `OnPropertyChanged(" ListOfInformation")` or better yet use [`CallerMemberName`](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Core/Mvvm/SimpleViewModel.cs)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help. I have found the bug for this binding issue. :)